# Remove namespace on property of type object in .NET XML serialization in API

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-namespaces

How can I get of this unnessary namespace on this XML property?  It can be either a decimal or integer.

```
<Score xmlns:d6p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d6p1:double">2.5</Score>
```

**Should be**

```
<Score>2.5</Score>
```

**Class**

```
[DataContract(Name = "Participant", Namespace = "")] 
public class ApiGameParticipant
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public object Score { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need your XML to look exactly like something or if you want to remove the namespace, then you might be better off with `XmlSerializer`. `DataContractSerializer` doesn't give you the same level of control as it's rather assumed you use it on both ends - and the namespace is critical in this regard as it addresses the consistent serialization and deserialization of types.

Comment: To change all my serializations to use XmlSerializer would be unnessary with how much the project uses it.  The XML currently is perfect, but for some reason using the type of object causes this one issue I have never seen before.

Comment: What issue are you running into?

Comment: I just told you above.  I dont want that stuff in my XML, I want it clean.

Comment: I understand your concern about the aesthetics - and i explained why the namespace is there and even necessary - i'm just asking if it's causing you any issues beyond "cosmetics".

Comment: No just cosmetics.  I assume I could make it a double to get what I actually want.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the namespace prefix "i" is bound in some containing element to `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`. If that's the case then your document won't be xsd-schema-valid if you remove the declaration of namespace `d6p1`. That's because the `xsi:type` attribute (as it's usually written) must be a QName, and to be a valid QName, the prefix part (in this case `d6p1`) must be declared.

Now perhaps you don't require your document to be schema-valid. In that case I would get rid of the `i:type` attribute as well. Keeping the attribute but losing the namespace declaration that gives it meaning seems like a really bad idea.

If you want to get rid of the attribute and namespace, it's easy enough with XSLT.

**LATER**

Looking at your question more carefully, I see that you do want to get rid of both the attribute and the namespace declaration. The XSLT code to do that (for all elements) is:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@i:type"
  xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

The first rule copies elements unchanged but without retaining unused namespaces; the second rule copies attributes unchanged; the third rule drops the `i:type` attribute.

Comment: Yes but do I use this XSD with my serialization?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What XSD?

Comment: How do I use the XSD with my serialization.  I basically made it a double instead of an object and it works fine that way so no biggie.

Comment: I don't know what you want to use XSD for. There are many ways of using XSD, e.g for validation, data binding, etc. This seems to be a completely unrelated question. I don't even know why you wanted to get rid of the xsi:type attribute in the first place.

Comment: Oh my bad, I mean XSLT not XSD, where would i use that.  You just stated there that might work, but you never gave a solution on how to use it.

Comment: Surely information on how to use XSLT under .NET is widely available? There's an XSLT 1.0 processor from Microsoft in System.Xml.Xsl, there's a native XSLT 2.0 processor from XmlPrime, and there's a 3.0 processor (ported from Java) from Saxonica. You're spoilt for choice.